# Different query plans for PostgreSQL db locally vs. on Heroku after pg_dump and pg_restore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I used `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` to move a large database (including 3 indexes) from my local machine to Heroku (following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65845796/1206439)). I have confirmed that:

- The Postgres versions are the same (13.2)
- The indexes are the same
- The number of rows are the same

And yet still the query plans for a certain type of query are different! This was working on a previous version of the same database -- created in the same way (just with fewer rows). Why could this be? The one locally takes less than 100ms, vs almost 90000ms on Heroku.

Below I'll outline some more details about the database:

```
           Column            |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |                   Default
-----------------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------
 id                          | integer           |           | not null | nextval('property_claims_id_seq'::regclass)
 PROPERTY_ID                 | integer           |           | not null |
 OWNER_NAME                  | character varying |           |          |

Indexes:
    "property_claim_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "gin_index_property_claims_on_OWNER_NAME" gin ("OWNER_NAME" gin_trgm_ops)
    "index_property_claims_on_OWNER_NAME" btree ("OWNER_NAME")
    "index_property_claims_on_PROPERTY_ID" btree ("PROPERTY_ID")
```

Locally:

```rb
PropertyClaim.where('"OWNER_NAME" like ?', "QUERY STRING%").explain
  PropertyClaim Load (32.5ms)  SELECT "property_claims".* FROM "property_claims" WHERE ("OWNER_NAME" like 'QUERY STRING%')
=> EXPLAIN for: SELECT "property_claims".* FROM "property_claims" WHERE ("OWNER_NAME" like 'QUERY STRING%')
                                                    QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using "index_property_claims_on_OWNER_NAME" on property_claims  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=2607 width=278)
   Index Cond: ((("OWNER_NAME")::text >= 'QUERY STRING'::text) AND (("OWNER_NAME")::text < 'QUERY STRINO'::text))
   Filter: (("OWNER_NAME")::text ~~ 'QUERY STRING%'::text)
(3 rows)
```

Remotely on Heroku:

```rb
PropertyClaim.where('"OWNER_NAME" like ?', "QUERY STRING%").explain
=>
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "property_claims".* FROM "property_claims" WHERE ("OWNER_NAME" like 'QUERY STRING%')
                                                  QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on property_claims  (cost=364.95..194660.14 rows=130938 width=728)
   Recheck Cond: (("OWNER_NAME")::text ~~ 'QUERY STRING%'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "gin_index_property_claims_on_OWNER_NAME"  (cost=0.00..358.41 rows=130938 width=0)
         Index Cond: (("OWNER_NAME")::text ~~ 'QUERY STRING%'::text)
 JIT:
   Functions: 2
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Did you run ANALYZE after loading the data?

Answer (score 3):

A btree index can only support a LIKE query if the pattern doesn't start with a wild card (you seem to be good there) and if either the collation is C, or if the index is created with one of the special operators such as text_pattern_ops.  So I'm guessing your local database has the collation as C, while Heroku does not.

If you create an index `ON property_claims ("OWNER_NAME" varchar_pattern_ops)` then you should get the faster plan on heroku too.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks so much for the background! I found out the default Collation locally (C) is different from Heroku (en_US.UTF8). One thing I tried though was setting the default collation for the `OWNER_NAME` column to C (locally, even though that's also the default), and that _changed_ the query plan (to no longer use the btree index). That was really surprising to me! Any idea why? I also learned you can't drop a custom Collation on a column, which was a bummer.