# How to connect already existing PostgreSQL database with Heroku?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I deployed my app using Heroku, but while deploying Heroku created a new PostgreSQL database. Now I need to change that to my already existing PostgreSQL database(I am using Django framework in VsCode), which I used while running in the localhost. Does anyone have an idea, please help me with this?.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a database dump and import it into your Heroku Postgres.
Use `pg_dump`to create a dump and then upload it to heroku.
A detailed description can be found [on the heroku dev center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

Additionally, there is a quite good Stackoverflow entry on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890084/importing-a-postgresql-dump-to-heroku)

According to this follow these steps and you should be fine.

Create a dump from the source PostgreSQL database

```
   $ PGPASSWORD=YOUR_PG_PASSWORD pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U YOUR_PG_USER YOUR_DB_NAME > YOUR_DB_NAME.dump
```

Get the Heroku Postgres credentials for your heroku app

```
$ heroku pg:credentials:url -a YOUR_APP_NAME
```

Attempt to import PostgreSQL dump to Heroku using the credentials above

```
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h HOSTNAME -U USER -d DATABASE -p PORT PATH/TO/YOUR_DB_NAME.dump --password
```

Enter the password received from the Heroku Postgres credentials
It should then import the dump successfully

Comment: How will you generate a signed URL? Whether will it be a canned policy or custom policy

Comment: I will update my answer as I have found a similar question